# How can I explain why my mechs don't sink into the ground?

Tags: science-based, warfare

Everybody loves the concept of mechs, but there is one big practical problem with them that gets worse the fewer legs they have: [ground pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_pressure). tl;dr: big heavy object on two small thin spindly ones isn't very good at not sinking into even the hardest ground.

Currently I'm handwaving past this issue with anti-gravity type generators installed in every mech (although these could have interesting tactical implications with respect to their failure), but I'd prefer something a little more substantial and/or closer to what we know today to make my worldscape more accessible to readers.

About the only thing I can come up with is some sort of ridiculously light and strong super-alloy, but that also feels like a somewhat obvious piece of "technological magic".

Comment: Whether its sinks or not will be dependant on your mechs size and density but they'd need to be ridiculously heavy before they'd starting "sinking" into solid ground.

Comment: @BMS21 That is simply incorrect. If you increase the size, the volume (and thus mass) increases with the power of 3, while the surface area increases with the power of 2. So your mech will have the same density, but higher mass/surface area. That means there is more mass per square meter for the legs. This is on example of the square-cube-law. There are many appliances for this law. Whether it's mechanical, thermodynamical and so on. Size increase changes the situation quite a bit.

Comment: @ArtificialSoul Even with the square cube law the ground (of course dependant on material) can take huge amounts of pressure and even if they are scaled up proportionally to a human they would have to become huge and therefore ridiculously heavy to overcome the grounds pressure limit.

Comment: You are aware that regular houses on most terrain need to get a foundation to prevent sinking, right? So as soon as we scale mechs up close to the weight of the house it is very reasonable to assume that they sink in some terrain - which is what OP wants to avoid. They do not need to be colossally huge to have this be a problem. Smaller than a house is probably problematic enough.

Comment: To put @ArtificialSoul 's point another way: if the mech weighs more than a house, and it's standing on ground weaker than the house's foundation, and its feet are smaller than the house, it's reasonable to expect it to sink into the ground.

Comment: *How fast* would houses without a foundation sink? A house is designed to remain in place for many decades, whereas a mech probably moves around often.

Comment: I think one of the problems is the word "sink." A mech would sink a bit into the ground, but it wouldn't act like it was in quicksand. Sorry, mechs are cool, but make no real sense without some form of magic (that is, non-scientific things like anti-gravity).

Comment: I honestly doubt any realistic mech would be heavy enough to properly sink into the ground unless designed to. I imagine it would leave a foot print and it would have trouble walking over loose soil or muddy land where it sinks in a lot more. But if you get large enough to worry about sinking into the ground your also going to have to worry about your huge motors and power as well as the impact on your mechs legs as it walks and supports its weight. I would say its perfectly reasonable to just say it left a foot print a few centimeters deep as it walks around on normal ground.

Comment: You just need big feet. Think of snowshoes for humans. Just make the feet have flaps that can be deployed to increase surface area.

Comment: "Ridiculously light and strong super-alloy" isn't so unrealistic, in fact. Skyscrapers don't sink into the ground because their load-bearing structure being made of steel beams rather than stone blocks makes them dramatically lighter than a regular building of the same shape would be.

Comment: If you have anti-grav technology, then the legs on the mech seem superfluous. They could just hover. Maybe you could just give them a skirt with no feet.

Comment: The elephant in the room wants to know what makes something that's so top heavy a viable weapons platform.

Answer (score 49):

## The ground is pretty strong

In an [answer to another question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/110142/23519), I demonstrate that a 20,000 ton kaiju shouldn't have too much trouble moving around on land, with feet only twice as large (area wise) relative to its body as a human.

A human sprinter puts out a ground reaction force of 3000 N or roughly 150 kPa (from that link). For a 100 ton mech (heavier than a main battle tank), ground force at rest is 1 MN (roughly), which requires only ~7 m$^2$ of foot surface area to yield equivalent ground pressure of a human sprinter's foot. Triple this for safety, and divide by four legs, and you would need each of the four 'feet' of the mech to be around 2 meters square in size. Not super large, not super impractical.

Comment: @LordFarquaad: Due to the related math involved, that also makes it impassable for humans.

Comment: As a side note, this is mostly why snow rackets work, they distribute the weight on a wider surface. It's also why on an ice crust it's safer to use vehicles with tracks than with wheels.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Curiously enough, due to the height difference of typical humans vs. typical pedestrian mechs some grounds that for tactical purposes are (nigh) impassable to humans may still be passable to mechs, e. g. not-too-deep swamps.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: I realized it can work in reverse too. If there's giant soft spots, a giant food can't pass, but small feet can navigate between.

Comment: This seems to be comparing the dynamic load of a sprinter sprinting to the static load of a mech just standing around. Also, it's a pretty small mech - not even as heavy as two M1 Abrams tanks.

Comment: @user2357112, what about the "triple this for safety" part?

Answer (score 12):

Warhammer 40k features [Titans](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Warlord-class_Titan), gigantic bipedal war machines ranging from 20 to 80 meters in height, layered in armour and bristling with weaponry.

They explicitly don't care about ground-pressure. Where they go, they leave meters-deep footprints and crush boulders to gravel. To a thousand ton walker, soil and rock might as well be ankle-deep mud.

However, the largest of them compensate for their extreme mass by using anti-gravity systems to reduce it. These don't so much hover as lighten the load enough to walk without sinking to the bedrock.

Comment: On the 40k anti-grav systems:  they also allow you to lower the centre of gravity (anti-grav the top, leave the feet at full weight) for stability

Comment: @Chronocidal: What you intend to lower has nothing to do with gravity and weight/lift, its proper name is the center of mass, and won't be shifted by anti-gravity.

Comment: @BenVoigt About 50:50 - the centre of mass, which won't change, will impact momentum, and how the mech reacts to forces from other objects.  The centre of gravity will drop, and relates to the force generated by gravity (a.k.a. "weight") acting on the mass of the mech itself - similar to the difference in control between front-wheel and rear-wheel drive.  But, because mass and weight are typically treatable as directly proportional, (barring extreme gravitational gradients such as the Lagrange points between 2 stars that are about to collide) these points are normally almost exactly the same.

Comment: I expect that rather depends on how your anti-gravity systems work. if they provide lift vs gravity then they don't affect mass or inertia, if they nullify mass in some way to make the vehicle physically lighter, that'd definitely affect the vehicle's center of mass.

Answer (score 11):

I've talked about it before, when your Mech starts growing you are going to need more legs. And using small excavator arms as legs it's practically feasible to have an 8 legged Mech of 100+tons, something that tanks have trouble with as the tanks are limited by length and width just as much as a Mech is limited by the square cube law.

If you want to have as few legs as possible then the biggest problem is ground pressure. However you can use that sagging into the ground as an advantage. For example instead of wider feet you create a spiked cone at the bottom that quickly widens. The surface of the cone already is larger than the surface of the feet. The cone will drive itself into the ground and as it does so the supportive surface grows. Additionally the weight of the Mech wont just push the earth down, it'll push it sideways meaning less groundpressure for the ground directly below it. Since you are also into the ground you have a better grip, allowing you to climb steeper inclines. This is also the part where a Mech becomes useful: it wont have lots of advantages in open terrain due to lower velocities but in hilly or mountain terrain a Mech's mobility would be higher than a tank. Still, making larger legs or splitting the feet into multiple smaller "legs" with a large surface area they stand on (and the ability to stand better on uneven terrain) are additional options.

Another often tauted disadvantage is disabling the legs. While a destroyed leg is definitely worse for a Mech than a tank, a Mech would be the only vehicle that can effectively armor the entirety of the leg. Additionally anyone firing at the legs themselves with an AT weapon would be send back to training as firing at the smaller and constantly accelerating/decelerating legs is a recipy for disaster. Anyone with training would aim for the joints where the legs meet the chassis which is practically the same as with a normal tank. That would make a Mech still less vulnerable to disabling fire due to the armor on the legs but the consequences for a successful hit are larger.

Edit: for those against the spike idea, you can easily expand on it and design better. For example a cylinder with a hollow shaped like a cone on the bottom of the feet: the edges are "sharp" and push the soil to the center of the cone where it compacts. It also adds surface area and even watery mud would get high pressures to support the feet as it goes deeper.

Comment: Regarding your idea of the spikes: While i do think it's a good solution it only works to a certain size. If your mech is colossal then it would have to lift its legs a lot for every step as it would have to pull out the spikes.

Comment: Also regarding the idea of the spikes: The mechs would be difficult/cumbersome to move over surfaces you don't want to poke full of holes. Mechs defending a critical airfield would be unable to cross the runways and taxiways, or else they'd do the enemy's work for them. The same applies to roads and bridges. Your mechs would need to be trailer-able onto some large truck with wheels to get them across paved surfaces. That would also be useful for moving the mechs to the frontlines quickly, as the truck could probably drive faster than the mech can walk.

Comment: @Jared K Mechs wouldnt be as useful as tanks for defending an airfield unless it's something like the Swiss mountain airfields. If you still want to use them there you do it like most vehicles do nowadays: modular. The airfield and surroundings are almost certainly made to handle heavy traffic so the ground is likely able to handle the pressure if you take the spikes off. Also you'd better be building Mech trenches, Mech's are perfect for popping up, firing and going down, then moving further along the trench. This is something tanks cant do as well.

Comment: @artificialsoul if you are talking about the 10+m tall 200+ton bipedal mechs with weapons out of every orifice then yes. But at that point you might as well make a 20m long tank with 5cm long tracks, say Segway made it and tracks are perfect for ground pressure and you've got about the same lunacy.

Comment: @Demigan Yes, i just wanted to add that to your answer since OP did not specify a size

Comment: One of my favourite walking vehicles in fiction is the [Onager Dunecrawler](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Onager_Dunecrawler), a vehicle from Warhammer 40k. It notably has the traditional Spikey Spider-Legs that should sink into the ground with every step, but augments them with deployable "snow shoes" for softer terrain.

Comment: Ack! No, no, no! By going to spikes you make the feet sink deeper for the same amount of weight. In effect, you increase the ability to penetrate the ground, and that is not what you're trying to do. " the weight of the Mech wont just push the earth down, it'll push it sideways". Exactly. And making it easier for the foot to push dirt out of it's way makes it sink deeper, not less.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast is right. Where do you think the earth underfoot goes when it seems to get pushed down? It doesn't push straight down in a column to the core, it gets smooshed or compacted sideways at some point. A spike foot will simply penetrate further into the ground because it makes it easier to push material out of the way and sink. The only advantage of spikes on the bottoms of feet is for horizontal grip and stability (like soccer cleats) but that's a different issue. If you want to not sink, flat wide feet are better (like snowshoes).

Comment: @Whatroughbeast it depends on the design. If the cone gets to the foot's full surface area it wont magically go deeper as by the time it reaches the end of the cone, far more surface area is pushing the earth and it has compacted it. Just think of Jareds snowshoes but with Spikes: https://goo.gl/images/8LcwiC. Ofcourse those are thin spikes, but a full spike as large as the shoe itself would not go as deep as the small one's.

Comment: With modern ATGM's and other guided weapons, aiming at the joints or moving legs is almost trivially easy. Only unguided weapons like APDS-FS shells from a tank or an RPG style infantry weapon would be prone to miss the moving limb, but the intelligent gunner would aim for the centre fo visible mass (the torso) anyway.

Comment: @Demigan - Oh for heaven's sake: those aren't showshoes, they're crampons. You don't wear them on snow, you wear them on ice. And the reason? They penetrate deeper into ice than regular sole patterns. Just like your mech would sink deeper with cones.

Comment: @Whatroughbeast how can I make you understand this? Think perhaps of an arrow. You make the cutting edge thin, but the area behind the edge should also be thin. If you make the arrow a cone as broad as the arrowhead's outer edges it will penetrate only a little bit as the surface area grows too quickly. Which is exactly what you want to achieve: penetrate into the ground for a portion (the "deeper" part) to increase grip on the ground while simultaneously spreading the forces on the ground. The angle of the cone also means its easier to pull out again than a "normal" foot.

Comment: @Demigan - How can I make YOU understand. As you make the cone blunter, it penetrates less. Yes! Exactly! The ultimate in blunt cones is one which has no point at all.

Comment: @Whatroughbeast I'm arguing for a leg that uses ground penetration as an advantage by making it increase grip and reduce the amount of penetration at a desired point while also offering a good design that is easy to pull out of the ground again. You are arguing that any penetration is automatically bad. But how about this: you calculate the surface area and ground pressure of a 1m diameter circle and a cone that had a base of 1m diameter and 45 degree angle to the point with both a 1 ton (1000kg) weight on top and see which is better. You can also use a piramid or wedge if you prefer.

Answer (score 11):

This toy has booms around 80 meters long and can weight up to 14,200 metric tons, depending on configuration:

[image: Bucket wheel excavator]

It leaves some tracks on dirt, but that's it. Notice how it goes around without sinking into the ground, which would be very bad for it since it has no legs.

As long as your mechs have a weight-to-surface ratio not less favourable than the bucket-wheel excavator's, and are not walking on quicksand, they shouldn't have to bother about sinking.

Comment: The [crawler](https://history.nasa.gov/ap11ann/kippsphotos/69-HC-617.jpg) transporting the Saturn V was even more impressive ;)

Comment: @L.Dutch it was only 2,700 tons heavy though. Baggers are usually five times heavier.

Comment: [Accordng to Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_pressure), that thing (or something similar) has less ground pressure than a bicycle, a car or an elephant. .

Comment: You've not mentioned what that thing is: the 'Bagger 293'.

Answer (score 8):

Larger feet are what camels use to prevent sinking into the desert. Your mechs could use that technique (it reduces pressure by increasing the area of force application). They could also have rockets or boosters of some sort to lift them out if they do get stuck.

Also, the idea of mechs sinking into the ground could be a cool plot device, explaining why mechs can't be used in a certain situation. Booster fuel could be a limitation on the amount of time a mech can walk before it has to return.

Answer (score 6):

From an engineering perspective, firm clay can take 10 tons or so (100kN) per square metre, without issue. That's the typical maximum loading for house foundations here in London, and they have to be reliable for decades or more.

Ignoring the massive safety factors built into that working, and **also** ignoring the need to be rigid (if the ground sinks a metre does the mech care?), and **also** ignoring the need for stability over time (gradual changes over decades don't matter), it wouldn't surprise me if you could safely load of the order of 10 times that on clay. And of course that's on a soft material.

Dynamic forces are a bit different but probably won't make much difference - if the mech can cope with a metre of ground movement as it places a foot, the dynamic force issue will probably be swallowed up within that movement, or by the mech's handling of foot placement, and feedback of ground support/resistance.

Short version - not a worry.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't change the properties of the mech - change the properties of the planet**

Given that it is not specified *where* the mech action is happening, set the action on a low gravity world (or worlds), rather than using handwavium to provide artificial antigravity.  Mechs are far less impractical in low gravity, where with the addition of jets/rockets they can blur the line between ground and air units.

This also has the advantage that the poor pilot/s stuck in the mech are subjected to less impact force from landings - movies love showing giant mechs making equally giant vertical leaps.  This ignores the fact that without the "knees" bending much more than typically shown on *every* landing, for the pilot a fall of 20m in a big mech is just as damaging as a fall of 20m in your average car (less survivable if the mech pilot is standing up miming the mech's actions).

Answer (score 3):

**Don´t use steel bodies**

Although iron and steel may be the first option that comes to our head when talking about mechs, we must not forget that actually there are many tracks of scientific investigation of new alternative materials that can be stronger than steel and weight much more less. Assuming the Mech technology is still many years in the future, it is not unlikely to suppose that Mechs could be made of a non-metallic composite material (much more lighter, and therefore with less risk of sink into the ground).

And the trick is not only in the material itself, but **in the way the material is shaped**. For example: a single sheet of paper cannot support itself horizontally between two separated bricks. But if you bend the sheet of paper and make a rectangular long box (a prism) you can colocate it horizontaly supported by the two separated bricks, and the same paper will support itself properly.

At a molecular level, you can play with the structures of some materials and enhance a desired characteristic. Take for example, the graphene: graphene is stronger than steel but breaks like glass. However, you can build a spongy graphene structure able to be lighter than the flimsiest plastic and 10 times stronger than steel (not commercially available yet, but works nicely in the laboratory).

With a more advanced manufacturing technology (in the same future where the mechs are fabricated) surely there will be more options like this.

Here is the link to that article about the graphene material:
https://www.livescience.com/57432-stronger-than-steel-material.html

EDIT: And just to clarify: This super-alloys are in no way "technological magic"
 :)

Comment: This is what I was thinking when I read it.  By the time we're actually using mechs, I would think we would have a wealth of structural "meta-materials" to play around with; along with much better analysis so that we can make smarter designs.  Finite element programs can already come up with some really cool designs when they are set to optimize materials vs. strength.  I could easily see new materials and new computer-driven analysis taking this really far in the next hundred years or so.

Answer (score 2):

More legs to spread the weight.

Also, you could have the legs "splay" a network of supporting struts at each step, multiplying the "feet" surface either above or immediately beneath the surface. In both cases, this has serious implications on the mech's deployability (can't walk on some kinds of terrains, and the mechs could be lamed by shooting at their feet - a very literal Achilles' heel).

Answer (score 1):

If you have two or more legs that distribute the weight of the mech over a larger portion of the ground, it should be feasible.

How large are your mechs going to be? This is a large factor in how much they weigh, and ultimately how large the "feet" need to be. I'd recommend looking into the mechs from *Chromehounds*, or even the Mantis from *Halo* for inspiration regarding mech leg structure.

Answer (score 0):

Have the setting be on a planet with less gravity. Overlapping a light alloy, big feet, and a lighter gravity setting would basically minimize the problem.

(An alternate to light gravity is a dense atmosphere and a mech filled with helium. idk how well it would work unless the atmosphere was super dense though.)

Answer (score 0):

Triangular pyramid shaped feet, distributes the weight in 3 directions.

But the key is with hydraulic shocks.

The triangular pyramid shaped feet hold it up and allow its gyro to find its balance. While the hydraulic shocks are what truly keep it from sinking in; as the feet touch the shocks kick in and ease the weight down, unlike plopping it down.

It's like the difference between dropping a bowling ball onto styrofoam vs placing it onto styrofoam. Dropping it destroys the styrofoam while placing it sees no change to its structure. The hydraulic shocks make it more like the weight is being placed onto the ground instead of just crashing into it.

That said, these would still have to be very impressive shocks and maybe hydraulic isnt strong enough but at least that's the direction I would focus on, or at least have my scientists focus on at least.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that in addition to increasing the size of the contact area of the feet, you also need to change the overall shape of the mech as well.

Given issues like the square/cube law and stability due to the centre of gravity, a mech won't scale up like some monster human, but rather will become wider, have "tree trunk" legs that are proportionally much wider than human legs and likely a relatively squat torso. The idea of "arms" is really a bit of a non starter as well, the changes to balance while moving multi ton arms around (much less the recoil of arm mounted weapons) would make moving and fighting immensely more complicated.

If anything, the form factor might be more like the "Huey, Dewey and Louie" robots from the 1970 era movie "[Silent Running](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067756/)"

[image]

*Sure they're cute now, but imagine if they were 20' tall and bristling with weapons*

OF course even with this they will still be vulnerable to virtually everything a modern military force can bring to bear, the Mech will have to deal with everything from 500lb "[Small Diameter Bombs](https://infogalactic.com/info/Small_Diameter_Bomb)" launched from a stealth F-35 100 km away to Infantry solders firing [Javelin](https://infogalactic.com/info/FGM-148_Javelin) "Fire and Forget" ATGM's from 4750 meters. Only truly deranged or desperate people would actually approach close enough to use an [RPG](https://infogalactic.com/info/Rocket-propelled_grenade) or [Carl Gustav](https://infogalactic.com/info/Carl_Gustav_recoilless_rifle) type anti tank weapon.

This suggests the Mech will likely have a large proportion of its carrying capacity devoted to countermeasures such as the [CIWS](https://infogalactic.com/info/Close-in_weapon_system), [Trophy](https://infogalactic.com/info/Trophy_(countermeasure)) active defence systems and 100kW lasers, rather than massive batteries of cannons and missiles. As a mobile protective system for a land based formation, you may have found the niche for Mechs in battle.

Comment: I refer you to the [Dreadnought](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Dreadnought)

Answer (score 0):

Your mechs could just roll around on tread in their feet instead of walking. That way you only have to worry about the weight to calculate pressure and not the amount of force your mech puts on the ground when it walks/run/does taekwando.

This would easily take care of explaining how your mechs are fast, and why their feet are so big. it would also allow you to Piggy back off of tread technology.

You should also start thinking about using some un-attain-ium techno-magic material like gundam does. In Gundam 00 the mechs are built with E carbon, which is just better Carbon fiber. In wing, Gundam's are literally built with Gundanium which is essentially a special blend of titanium built in such a way that it ends up with a damn near perfect matrix - the molecules are all packed uniformly - with highly advantageous properties. You're going to want to make your mechs light since you're going for realism.

Another solution is straight out of pretty much every mech anime. Your Mechs don't walk that much, they fly. This is another popular solution I've seen to how your mech doesn't break the ground while landing after a running jump kick or something else a little dumb.

Look at how much force you put on the ground running vs walking vs standing. There's quite a difference. Just having large feet to reduce pressure isn't the only thing to consider.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion anti-gravitation devices should not be used as such an explanation. Any Society which has technology on that level would have weapons available which far exceed our imagination and definitely no needs for mechs in the conventional sense. So unless you introduce a very good explanation (e.g. they found devices from another civilization).

Answer (score -1):

'Big feet' (surface area) seems to be the general solution, in addition to "They sink into the ground a bit". Largest land animal being the elephant, foot diameter of 40-50cm, area of about 2 square feet, 13,000 lbs, 2 legs, 3,500 lbs. per foot?

Comment: There is already a well written answer already addressing the contact area.